# CheckedListBox data binding to checked state of Items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, checkedlistbox

I tried to set DataSource of CheckedListBox like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Checked";
        _bindingList = new BindingList<CustomBindingClass>(
            new List<CustomBindingClass>
        {
            new CustomBindingClass {Checked = CheckState.Checked, Name = "Item1"},
            new CustomBindingClass {Checked = CheckState.Checked, Name = "Item2"},
            new CustomBindingClass {Checked = CheckState.Unchecked, Name = "Item3"},
        });
        checkedListBox1.DataSource = _bindingList;
    }
```

And It's working but partially. I'm able to do the fallowing later

```
_bindingList.RemoveAt(0);
```

or `_bindingList[0].Name = "TestTest";` and CheckedListBox updates well except items are not checked. This is not working

```
_bindingList[0].Checked=CheckState.Checked;
```

I also tested to do it when `Checked`Property from my `CustomBindingClass` is of type bool, but doesn't works either. Any suggestion what should be the type of `ValueMember` property ?

Comment: `CustomBindingClass` need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or whatever it is called)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider these facts:

1. `CheckedListBox` does't have a built-in data-binding support for checking items. You need to handle check state of items yourself.
2. You set `checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Checked";`. You didn't set item check state, you just said when you select the item, the value which returns by `SelectedValue` comes from `Checked` property of your object which is behind the seected item. For example you can use this code in a `Click` event of a `Button` to see the result; regardless of check-state of items, the message box, will show value of `Checked` property of the object behind the item:

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
   ```
3. Selecting and checking items are completely different.

I prefer to use `DataGridView` for such purpose. You can simply have a `CheckBox` column and a readonly `TextBox` column and bind `DataGridView` to the list of your objects.

If you need to have two-way data binding, you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface regardless of what control you are using to show data. If you don't implement that interface, when changing properties on your model `ListChange` event will not raise and you can not see changes in UI automatically.

Comment: I know you want to use data-binding for checking and unchecking items of `CheckedListBox`. But unfortunately it doesn't have built-in support for data-binding to check states.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `CheckedListBox` class, you'll notice that `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are marked with

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

This a common technique used in Windows Forms controls to indicate that some public properties inherited from a base class (hence cannot be removed) are not applicable for that concrete derived class and should not be used.

There must be a reason for doing that for the aforementioned properties of the `CheckedListBox`. As you already saw, it's "sort of working", but the point is that it isn't guaranteed to work at all. So don't use them. If you wish, create a helper class that holds `CheckedListBox` and `BindingList`, listens to `ListChanged` event and synchronizes the control.