# How can I bind the checked property of CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Question**
>
> How can I bind a
>   `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox`?

---

> **What I've tried**
>
> **Class**
>
> ```
> public class Foo
>     {
>         public string Description { get; set; }
>         public bool isSelected { get; set; }
>     }
> ```
>
> > **Usage**
>
> ```
>         List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
>         Foo foo = new Foo();
>         foo.Description = "One";
>         foo.isSelected = true;
>         fooList.Add(foo);
>         foo = new Foo();
>         foo.Description = "Two";
>         foo.isSelected = false;
>         fooList.Add(foo);
>         foo = new Foo();
>         foo.Description = "Three";
>         foo.isSelected = true;
>         fooList.Add(foo);
>
>         var fooBindingList = new BindingList<Foo>(fooList);
>         var source = new BindingSource(fooBindingList, null);
>         clbFoo.DataSource = source;
>         clbFoo.DisplayMember = "Description";
>         clbFoo.ValueMember = "isSelected";
> ```

---

> **Result**
>
> The DisplayMember is visible, but the checkboxes aren't checked.

**EDIT**: I originally put "one-way binding" in the question, but it doesn't matter if it's one-way or two-way binding, so I've removed "one-way" from the question.

**EDIT**: I know this can be done manually. I want to know if it can be done by binding.

```
    foreach (Foo item in fooList)
    {
        clbFoos.Items.Add(item, item.isSelected);
    }
```

Comment: `CheckedListBox` doesn't have built-in support for data-binding to check state of items. In such cases I prefer to use `DataGridView` instead. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39076505/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you. Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I can close this?

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted the answer for a similar question in the link which I shared. You can vote for the linked question and answer if you liked them :)

Comment: Done. I've upvoted your answer in the other question. I'll also vote to close this question as a duplicate. However, the other question title is very poorly worded ("CheckedListBox bind ValueMember"), so I'll edit that title.

Comment: I edited the title of linked question to make it more clear. Also your question will help future readers to find the linked post.