# SelectedItem String for method

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

i have a question. I select a Item from a dropdown. Now i like to use this selected item to change the values of a CheckedListbox. The data with the values for the CheckedListbox are in classes. For Example:

In the DropDown I can select Machine 1 and Machine 2.
If I select Machine 1 the CheckedListbox show me Option 1, Option2 and Option 3. The Classes have different Names but the array with the options are in both Classes the same name.

I don't can't call the method with a string because a string is variable. How can i solve this?
Thanks for your help.

Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cbox.Items.AddRange(new ListMachinetyp().machinetype);
}
private void cbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = cbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    clb1.Items.Clear();
    lbl.Text = selectedItem.ToString();
    clb1.Items.AddRange(new cbox.SelectedItem.ToString().options);
}
```

Machine1.cs

```
public class Machine1
{
    public string[] options = new string[] {
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "Option 3"
        };
}
```

Machine2.cs

```
public class Machine2
{
    public string[] options = new string[] {
        "Option 2",
        "Option 5"
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    List<string> machineNames = new List<string>();
    machineNames.Add("Machine 1");
    machineNames.Add("Machine 2");
    cbox.DataSource = machineNames; // you can use any other list
}

void SetCheckedListboxSource(string selectedItem)
{
    if (selectedItem == "Machine 1") // you can also say if (selectedItem == machineNames[0])
       {
           Machine1 mach1 = new Machine1();
           checkedListBox.DataSource = null;
           checkedListBox.DataSource = mach1.options;
       }
    else if (selectedItem == "Machine 2") // you can also say if (selectedItem == machineNames[1])
       {
           Machine2 mach2 = new Machine2();
           checkedListBox.DataSource = null;
           checkedListBox.DataSource = mach2.options;
       }
}

private void cbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = cbox.Text;
    
    SetCheckedListboxSource(selectedItem);
}
```

This is basic C# practice my friend. People on this site don't answer questions like this, I only answered because you seem to be new to this. Keep practicing, good luck ♥

Answer (score 0):

Your post does an excellent job of describing a *behavior* where the list of options is filtered according to the configuration selected in the drop down list. One of many ways to achieve this outcome is to create a list of *all* options and then assign the `DataSource` of the `CheckedListControl` to a binding list of options containing only those that match.

[image: screenshot]

A savvy coder will likely be thinking about ways to tightly associate the name of a configuration (e.g. "Machine 1") with the options it requires. One approach is to design a class that models the desired behavior:

```
class OptionsConfig
{
    public string Device { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string[] Options { get; set; } = new string[0];
}
```

---

You hit the nail on the head when you said that you **can't call the method with a string because a string is variable** but now the problem is solved. The items in the "DropDown" are `OptionsConfig` instances instead of strings. This is configured in the method that loads the main form. The `DataSource` property of the combo box to a `BindingList<OptionsConfig>`:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    comboBox.DataSource = _optionConfigs;
    comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(OptionsConfig.Device);

    // This 'will' still compile for CheckedListBox.
    // Don't be fooled when intellisense doesn't show it.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39076505/5438626
    listBox.DataSource = _filteredOptions;
    listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

    // Add some machines and options to test.
    CreateMachineConfigs();
    CreateUnfilteredOptionList();

    // Init to selected item and attach handler for future changes.
    onOptionsChooserChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += onOptionsChooserChanged;
    listBox.SelectedValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        propertyGrid.SelectedObjects = 
        listBox.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    };
}
```

Now filter the options when the config changes, for example from **Machine 1** to **Machine 2**:

```
private void onOptionsChooserChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _filteredOptions.Clear();
    var config = (OptionsConfig) comboBox.SelectedItem;
    foreach (var option in config.Options)
    {
        var found = _allOptions.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Option.Equals(option));
        if(found != null)_filteredOptions.Add(found);
    }
    listBox.Refresh();
    ActiveControl = null;
}
```

---

**Consider using PropertyGrid**

The `CheckedListBox` control may not be an ideal choice, however. In particular, it doesn't offer strong support for data binding. An alternative is using a `PropertyGrid` control in conjunction with a `ListBox`. The `PropertyGrid` will reconfigure itself automatically based on the selection in the `ListBox' and possibly save you a lot of work.

[image: property grid]

---

**Testing**
Create some mock machine configs for test.

```
    BindingList<OptionsConfig> _optionConfigs = new BindingList<OptionsConfig>();
    private void CreateMachineConfigs()
    {
        _optionConfigs.Add(new OptionsConfig
        {
            Device = "Machine 1",
            Options = new[] { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" },
        });
        _optionConfigs.Add(new OptionsConfig
        {
            Device = "Machine 2",
            Options = new[] { "Option 2", "Option 5", },
        });
    }
}
```

Create list of option classes where "the Classes have different Names".

```
BindingList<OptionClass> _allOptions = new BindingList<OptionClass>(); 
BindingList<OptionClass> _filteredOptions = new BindingList<OptionClass>();  
private void CreateUnfilteredOptionList()
{
    _allOptions.Add(new OptionClassB { Option = "Option 1" });
    _allOptions.Add(new OptionClassA { Option = "Option 2" });
    _allOptions.Add(new OptionClassA { Option = "Option 3" });

    _allOptions.Add(new OptionClassA { Option = "Option 4" });
    _allOptions.Add(new OptionClassB { Option = "Option 5" });
}
BindingList<OptionsConfig> _optionConfigs = new BindingList<OptionsConfig>();
```

---

**Classes**

Minimal examples of option classes with different names.

**Option base class**

```
abstract class OptionClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Option { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Description("Enable this option.")]
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isChecked, value))
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsChecked)));
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _isChecked = false;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged; 
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public override string ToString() => Option;
}
```

**Fruit option class example**

```
enum Fruit
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange,
}
class FruitOptionClass : OptionClass
{
    [Description(@"Choose a fruit.")]
    public Fruit Fruit
    {
        get => _fruit;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_fruit, value))
            {
                _fruit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    Fruit _fruit = 0;
}
```

**Pet option class example**

```
enum Pet
{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Gerbil,
}
class PetOptionClass : OptionClass
{
    [Description("Pick a species for your pet.")]
    public Pet Pet
    {
        get => _pet;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_pet, value))
            {
                _pet = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    Pet _pet = 0;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dropdown-bound-options.git) minimal sample.